# intel realsense R200 random noise on ROS

Tags: ros, noise, depth, realsense

I'm trying to use the R200 on a mobile robot for obstacle detection. I keep getting these random points in the point cloud data:

[image: R200 in Rviz]

they appear even in ideal conditions and lighting, flickering while the real objects stay relatively steady. Could this be a configuration problem, or is this just a limitation of the sensor?

Comment: Is there something blocking the camera's view?

Comment: no I think it's just the nature of the camera

Answer (score 0):

found this issue on the intel-realsense-ros github:
https://github.com/intel-ros/realsense/issues/50

I guess there will just be some noise in the raw data. For now I'm using the rtabmap_ros/point_cloud_xyz nodelet to filter out the noise, although I still get the occasional phantom floating point.